# How to use Apache ignite SqlQuery With Java Set

Tags: java, sql, ignite

I am setting up a new java program with ignite and java to search sets that contain ignite cache.

I have set Class A indexed by id with two String sets : Set A1 and Set A1 annotated with SqlQueryField. I have as input a String java set A3 for example and I want to check if the cached sets A1 and A1 contains all the elements of A3 using sql query engine of ignite or with sqlCursor .

```
Cached A1 ( a1,a2,a3 )
Cached A2 ( a1,a2 )
Input A3 (a1)
```

I expect the output to be the index of A where A1 and A2 contain all the elements of A3 without using java loop code or streams, just with ignite engine.

Comment: I don't see java here. Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

Apache Ignite does not support collection destructuring in SQL. This means you can't peek inside collections in SQL queries.

However, you could try creating a [custom SQL function](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/custom-sql-functions) which takes string and indexed field as argument, returns boolean.

Comment: Is there any example for searching in indexed field with set or list of inputs ? Is there any performance enhancement ?

Comment: I didn't see any, and no.

Comment: what about arrays?

Comment: Same thing with arrays - no destructuring.